# Unable to pass SSL Client Cert to IBM MQ from Nodejs/MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR/MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I'm trying to push messages to IBM MQ through secure SSL Channel. This is my first nodejs application that integrates with MQ, though I've done this in the past using .net. I've tried the following code, but getting exception below exception.

```
let hConn;
let cD = new msmq.MQCD();
let cno = new msmq.MQCNO();
let oD = new msmq.MQOD()
oD.ObjectName = config.queueName;
cD.ConnectionName = config.port;
cD.ChannelName = config.channel;
cD.CertificateLabel = config.certLabel; 
cD.SSLCipherSpec = config.cipherSpec;

    msmq.Connx(config.queueManager, cno, (err, hConn) => {
    msmq.Open(hConn, oD, openOptions, (err, hObj) => {
    let mqmd = new msmq.MQMD();
                let pmo = new msmq.MQPMO();
    msmq.Put(hObj, mqmd, pmo, message, (err) => {})

    })

    })
```

Error:

```
error fields.name:MQError fields.message:CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR [2381] [Pkg ver = 0.5.1] fields.mqrcstr:MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR fields.stack:MQError: CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR
```

I'm sure that it has something to do with this line of code, but I couldn't find any other apt property either to set the cert name or the path as I did in .net (SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, this is the property I used there). Any help is highly appreciated.

cD.CertificateLabel = config.certLabel;

Here is my latest code, but still getting the same error

```
let hConn;
let cD = new msmq.MQCD();
let cno = new msmq.MQCNO();
let oD = new msmq.MQOD();
let cO=new msmq.MQSCO;

oD.ObjectName = config.queueName;
cD.ConnectionName = config.port;
cD.ChannelName = config.channel;
cD.SSLCipherSpec = config.cipherSpec;
cO.KeyRepository = 'path of the cert file' (.pfx)

    cno.ClientConn = cD;
    cno.SSLConfig=cO;

    msmq.Connx(config.queueManager, cno, (err, hConn) => {
    msmq.Open(hConn, oD, openOptions, (err, hObj) => {
    let mqmd = new msmq.MQMD();
                let pmo = new msmq.MQPMO();
    msmq.Put(hObj, mqmd, pmo, message, (err) => {})

    })

    })
```

Solution:

I ended up solving my problem by passing both keyRepo and certLabel and the cert files in .kdb and .sth format. There was an issue that I faced with username being more than 12 characters, hence I used certLabel with less than 12 characters identifier after the standard 'ibmwebspheremq'

```
     cO.CertificateLabel = config.certLabel; 
     cO.KeyRepository = 'path of the cert file and key name' (no extension in the file name)
```

Client .ini file (in its SSL section) CertificateLabel attribute - this step from the link below is must to get the above code working, in fact you don't even need to pass certificate label if you have this set up at the server side

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014340_.htm

Answer (score 0):

The MQSCO structure is used to name the keystore. Then that is attached to the MQCNO along with the MQCD.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I figured it so after my initial post, by digging in to the MQ library.

Answer (score 0):

In MQ, the first thing you need to look for is the Reason Code.

> MQError: CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC =
>   MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR

Reason Code of MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR (2381) is the important bit.  If you look in the MQ KnowLedge Center [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q044090_.htm) you will see:

*On an MQCONN or MQCONNX call, the location of the key repository is either not specified, not valid, or results in an error when used to access the key repository. The location of the key repository is specified by one of the following:*

- *The value of the MQSSLKEYR environment variable (MQCONN or MQCONNX
  call), or*
- *The value of the KeyRepository field in the MQSCO structure*
  (MQCONNX call only).

*For the MQCONNX call, if both MQSSLKEYR and KeyRepository are specified, the latter is used.*

Comment: Actually, I figured that out after my post last night, i've changed my code to use MQSCO and attach is to MQCNO along with the MQCD, but now I'm getting a different error saying 'input string is too long for the MQI field'. i'm using .pfx cert. Has it got something todo with the way the cert if created?

Comment: I figured out why i'm getting the error 'input string is too long for the MQI field' and resolved it, but i'm back to my original error MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR.

Comment: You need to import the pfx certificate into a CMS (.kdb) keystore.